# Script that runs at login and logout

Tags: macos, authentication, logout, osx-elcapitan, login-script

To count my time at work i would need to log the time i logged in, and the time i logged out from my session.
I am using OSX El Capitan.
That would allow me to calculate the timediff between both timestamps and so calculate the amount of hours i spent at work per week.

This could be achieved quite easily in a script that would write the time of login and logout into a file.
I did the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "log from $1" >> /Users/me/Documents/startup/time.log 
date >> /Users/me/Documents/startup/time.log
```

I tried this using `LoginHook`, but it seems deprecated in El Capitan.

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /Users/me/Documents/startup/script.sh
```

Of course my script is executable.

I thought about using `daemons` like [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ), but is it really a good idea ? because i only want my script to work at login and logout?

Or shall i use a `.plist`, like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/295924/how-to-run-a-script-at-login-logout-in-os-x) ?

Or maybe Parse the system logs ?

I also tried to launch my script like [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21985?locale=en_US), but here again i woulnd't get the logout time...

What would be the proper way of doing such a thing?